# Отскакивание движущегося тела от стен внутри другого движущегося тела. Js

Tags: javascript, canvas

**Мне надо, чтобы, когда шарик попадёт внутрь квадрата, он двигался внутри, постоянно отскакивая от стен квадрата.** Вот набросок моего кода:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
let rect = new Image();
let ball = new Image();
rect.onload = function() {
  c.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 50, 50);
};
ball.onload = function() {
  c.drawImage(this, 250, 250, 20, 20);
};
rect.src = "https://www.proza.ru/pics/2011/11/09/230.jpg";
ball.src = "https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg";

class RouletteGame {
  constructor() {
    this.rects = [];
    this.start = false;
  }

  drawImage(i) {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.drawImage(this.rects[0].object, this.rects[0].x1, this.rects[0].y1, this.rects[0].width, this.rects[0].width);
    c.drawImage(this.rects[10].object, this.rects[10].x1, this.rects[10].y1, this.rects[10].width, this.rects[10].width);
  }

  ballMove(i, operation = 'minus') {
    //Движение по эллипсу
    if (operation === 'plus') {
      this.rects[i].x1 = this.rects[i].x + ((this.rects[i].radius) * Math.sin(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.sin(0) + (1.4 * (this.rects[i].radius - 5) * Math.cos(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.cos(0);
    } else {
      this.rects[i].x1 = this.rects[i].x + ((this.rects[i].radius) * Math.sin(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.sin(0) - (1.4 * (this.rects[i].radius - 5) * Math.cos(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.cos(0);
    }

    this.rects[i].y1 = this.rects[i].y + (1.2 * (this.rects[i].radius - 15) * Math.cos(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.sin(0) + (1.2 * (this.rects[i].radius - 15) * Math.sin(this.rects[i].angle)) * Math.cos(0);
    this.rects[i].angle += 0.008;
    this.drawImage();
  }

  create() {
    this.rects.push({
      object: rect,
      angle: 0,
      x: 250,
      y: 225,
      x1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      width: 50,
      radius: 100
    });


    this.rects[10] = {
      object: ball,
      angle: 0,
      x: 250,
      y: 225,
      x1: 250,
      x2: 250,
      dx: 1,
      dy: 1,
      width: 15,
      radius: 150
    };
  }

  update() {

    //Проверяем, что шарик внутри квадрата
    if (this.rects[10].x1 > this.rects[0].x1 && this.rects[10].x1 + this.rects[10].width < this.rects[0].x1 + this.rects[0].width && this.rects[10].y1 > this.rects[0].y1 && this.rects[10].y1 + this.rects[10].width < this.rects[0].y1 + this.rects[0].width) {
      this.start = true;
    }

    this.ballMove(0)

    if (this.start) {
      //Меняем направление движения по x
      if (this.rects[10].x1 <= this.rects[0].x1 || this.rects[10].x1 >= this.rects[0].object.x1 + this.rects[0].width) {
        this.rects[10].dx = -this.rects[10].dx;
      }
      //Меняем направление движения по y
      if (this.rects[10].y1 - 5 <= this.rects[0].y1 || this.rects[10].y1 + 5 >= this.rects[0].y1 + this.rects[0].width) {
        this.rects[10].dy = -this.rects[10].dy;
      }

      this.rects[10].x1 += this.rects[10].dx;
      this.rects[10].y1 += this.rects[10].dy;
    } else {
      this.ballMove(10, 'plus');

      if (this.rects[10].radius > 90) {
        this.rects[10].radius -= 0.2;
      }

    }
  }
}

const roulette = new RouletteGame();
new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      roulette.create(); //Создаём объекты
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  })
  .then(function() {
    setInterval(() => {
      roulette.update(); //Обновляем холст
    }, 20)
  });
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

**1)** Ошибка 1: шарик попадает внутрь и как будто сталкивается с невидимой стеной - она не позволяет пройти ему дальше;

**2)** Рано или поздно шарик выскакивает из квадрата.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Если у вас шарик застревает в стенке, то при столкновении со стенкой, кроме изменения направления сделайте сдвиг на количество пикселей, которые шарик прошел внутри стенки, чтобы его вытолкнуть

Comment: @gil9red, он у меня застревает вообще в какой-то невидимой и несуществующей стенке. Не понимаю, откуда она берётся, если у меня зависимость от границ квадрата